# What happens when multiple calls are placed using new-operator call to Class() in heap?

Tags: java, object, new-operator, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

When we make calls like below :-

```
class Class{
int x;
public Class(int a){
 x = a;
}
public void display(){
 System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

And in main method, then we use the class' object to display data :-

```
new Class(5).display();    // object 1
new Class(7).display();    // object 2
```

Now, my question is :-

> Whether what I've represented from object 1 and object 2 will be equal or
>   distinct(in terms of memory locations in heap)? Whether two separate
>   memory locations will be created in heap(dynamic memory allocator) OR
>   whether the same object(memory location in heap) will be used?

I am having this confusion since a long time. Also I am merely a noob in Java.

Please elaborate with respect to the heap section/dynamic memory allocation to Class object using `new` call.

Comment: Your class is called `A`, but you create `new Class`?

Comment: Your code will unlikely to compile as you have uppercase `Class` and actual classname is `A`, not the `Class`. Could you please check your code with compiler and then edit the question submitting working code?

Comment: @TagirValeev- Sorry, edited that. That mistype! But, I hope the general idea is clear to you guys!

Comment: I assume by `object x` you mean the instantiation result from `new Class()`, not the return of `display()`. Then the answer is they are separated.
And please next time don't you the `Class` for your dummy class name, it is easily be confused with [Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you create two objects with `new` operator they will look for you as different objects in the heap. So if you compare then with `==` they won't much. However if your code is JIT-compiled, heap allocation will not occur at all as JIT-compiler is smart enough to inline the constructor and `display()` method and conclude that it can be just rewritten to

```
System.out.println(5);
System.out.println(7);
```

But if you actually compare them with `==`, then probably this optimization will be turned off and two distinct objects will be allocated on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

It will be Two distict objects in the heap,every time you use the new operator

```
public class Test {
int x;
public Test(int a){
 x = a;
}
public void display(){
 System.out.println(x);
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    Test firstInstance = new Test(5);
    Test secondInstance = new Test(5);
    if(firstInstance == secondInstance)
        System.out.println("same");
    else
    {
        System.out.println("firstInstance"+firstInstance);
        System.out.println("secondInstance"+secondInstance);
    }
}
```

}